# Использование use

Tags: php, namespace

Допустим, есть класс `Mysql` который должен быть в пространстве `lib`

И классы `Library` с `Engine` которые живут в пространстве `engine`

Допустим, я хочу писать по человечески не используя тысячи объявлений `use` и не обращаясь к классам `через\нескончаемые\вагоны\пространства\имен`

Сейчас надо делать как-то так

```
namespace lib;

use engine\Engine as Engine;
use engine\Library as Library;


class Mysql extends Library {

    public function Init() {
       Engine::Say('Test');
    }
}
```

Можно ли делать как-то так?

```
namespace lib;

use engine; // Вжух, и все пространство имен "распаковано" сюда

class Mysql extends Library {

    public function Init() {
       Engine::Say('Test');
    }
}
```

Или так?

```
use engine; // Вжух, и все пространство имен "распаковано" сюда

// Говорим, что Mysql теперь в lib без всяких namespace
class lib\Mysql extends Library {

    public function Init() {
       Engine::Say('Test');
    }
}
```

Кто как вообще избегает всей этой каши?

Comment: в php7 можно написать вот так: `use engine\ { Engine, Library, someAnotherClass, EtcClass };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прям так нельзя, но можно короткий псевдоним:

```
namespace lib;

use engine as E; // Вжух, и все пространство имен "распаковано" сюда

class Mysql extends E\Library {

    public function Init() {
       E\Engine::Say('Test');
    }
}
```

Comment: в 7 версии еще так: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations  .